# How do I get Global variables int high and into low to print in display function? (These two variables display the highest and lowest marks)

Tags: c++, variables, get, global

The purpose of this program is to create a report card for a student. I have an error displaying the highest and lowest mark in the display function. I declared the variables int high and int low globally thinking that this would solve the problem- however it still prints zero in the display.- Funnt thing is prints the highest and lowest int the min max function
#include 
using namespace std;

```
int high; int low;

void studentDetails(string Name, string Surname, string School)
{
    cout << "Please provide the following details below.";
    cout << "\nName: ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Surname: ";
    cin >> Surname;
    cout << "Name of School: ";
    cin >> School;
}
getMarks (int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){

    cout << "Please provide the mark obtained (0-100) for the following subjects.";
    cout << "\nEnglish: ";
    cin >> Eng;
    while (Eng>=0 && Eng<=100){
        cout << "Mathematics: ";
        cin >> Maths;
    while (Maths>=0 && Maths<=100){
        cout << "Life Orientation: ";
        cin >> LO;
    while (LO>=0 && LO<=100){
        cout << "History: ";
        cin >> His;
    while (His>=0 && His<=100){
        cout << "Computer Literacy: ";
        cin >> CL;
    while (CL>=0 && CL<=100){
        cout << "Art: ";
        cin >> Art;
    while (Art>=0 && Art<=100){
        cout << "All marks have been recorded";
        return 0;
}}}}}}}

void AverageYearMark(int avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    avg = (Eng + Maths + LO + His + CL + Art)/6;
    cout << "\nThe average of the above marks is: ";
    cout << avg;
}

minMax(int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    int high = arr[0]; //highest mark

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        if(arr[i]>high){
        high = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Highest mark";
    cout << high;

    int low = arr[0]; // lowest mark

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        if(arr[i]<low){
        low = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Lowest mark";
    cout << low;
    return 0;
}

void passorFail (string dec, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr[] = {Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    int counta = 0;
    if(Eng>= 50){
        counta++;
        for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            if(arr[i]>50){
                counta++;
            }}
        if(counta>=4){
            dec = "Pass";
        }
        else{
            dec = "Fail";
        }
            }
    else{
        dec = "Fail";
        }
    cout << dec;
    }
void awardDistinction(double& avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr1[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    string arr2[6];
    string overall;
    string distinction = "distinction";
    for(int i= 0; i<6;i++){
        if(arr1[i]>=75){
            arr2[i]= distinction;
        }
        else{
            arr2[i] = " ";
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    cout << arr2[i];

    if(avg>=75){
       overall = "distinction";
    }
}
void codeSymbol(string (&symbol)[6], int (&code)[6],double& avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr1[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    //symbol<string,6>;
    //code<int,6>;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(arr1[i]>=80 && arr1[i]<=100){
            symbol[i] = "A";
            code[i] = 7;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=70 && arr1[i]<=79){
            symbol[i] = "B";
            code[i] = 6;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=60 && arr1[i]<=69){
            symbol[i] = "C";
            code[i] = 5;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=50 && arr1[i]<=59){
            symbol[i] = "D";
            code[i] = 4;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=40 && arr1[i]<=49){
            symbol[i] = "E";
            code[i] = 3;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=30 && arr1[i]<=39){
            symbol[i] = "F";
            code[i] = 2;
    }
        if(arr1[i]>=0 && arr1[i]<=29){
            symbol[i] = "FF";
            code[i] = 1;
    }
    }
    int avcode;
    string avsym;
    if(avg<=100 && avg>=80 ){
        avcode = 7;
        avsym  = "A";
    }
    if(avg<=79 && avg>=70 ){
        avcode = 6;
        avsym  = "B";
    }
    if(avg<=69 && avg>=60 ){
        avcode = 5;
        avsym  = "C";
    }
    if(avg<=59 && avg>=50 ){
        avcode = 4;
        avsym  = "D";
    }
    if(avg<=49 && avg>=40 ){
        avcode = 3;
        avsym  = "E";
    }
    if(avg<=39 && avg>=30 ){
        avcode = 2;
        avsym  = "F";
    }
    if(avg<=29 && avg>=0 ){
        avcode = 1;
        avsym  = "FF";
    }

    }
```

There error is when printing the highest and lowest mark in the display function below- it prints from the min max function but not when i get it globally

```
 void Dispay(string& Name, string& Surname, string& School, string (&symbol)[6] , int (&mark)[6], int (&code)[6], string (subject)[6]){

    cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    cout <<"            STUDENT ACADEMIC RECORD                            " << endl;
    cout <<" This program input the learner marks of matric level subjects and prints the student final report" << endl;
    cout <<"*******************************************************************************" << endl;

    cout <<"Name: " + Name + " " + Surname + "  School: " + School;

    cout <<"\n\nSubject \t\tMark\t\tSymbol\t\tCode" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<6;i++){
        cout << subject[i] << "\t" << mark[i]<< "%\t\t" + symbol[i] << "\t\t" << code[i] << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\nAverage Year Mark: " << " 32 " << " with symbol " << " D " << " and code " << " 4 " << endl;
    cout << "\nOutcome: " << "Passed" << endl;

    cout << "\nThe highest mark was: " << " -" <<high<< endl;
    cout << "\nThe lowest mark was: " << " -" <<low<< endl;
    cout <<"*******************************************************************************" << endl;

}



int main (){
string n; string sn; string s; string dec;
int Eng; int Maths; int LO; int His; int CL; int Art; int low; int high;
double avg = 0;
string subject[] = {"English          ","Mathematics      ","Life Orientation ","History          ","Computer Literacy","Art              "};
string symbol[6];
int code[6];

studentDetails(n,sn,s);
getMarks(Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
int mark[] = {Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art};

AverageYearMark(avg, Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
minMax(Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
passorFail(dec,Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
awardDistinction(avg, Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
codeSymbol(symbol,code,avg,Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL,Art);
Dispay(n,sn,s,symbol,mark,code,subject);
}




///Output:

Please provide the following details below.
Name: Imraan
Surname: JAcobs
Name of School: WIndereme
Please provide the mark obtained (0-100) for the following subjects.
English: 60
Mathematics: 85
Life Orientation: 62
History: 90
Computer Literacy: 96
Art: 97
All marks have been recorded
The average of the above marks is: 81Highest mark97Lowest mark60Pass distinction distinctiondistinctiondistinction
*******************************************************************************
            STUDENT ACADEMIC RECORD
 This program input the learner marks of matric level subjects and prints the student final report
*******************************************************************************
Name:    School:

Subject                 Mark            Symbol          Code
English                 60%             C               5
Mathematics             85%             A               7
Life Orientation        62%             C               5
History                 90%             A               7
Computer Literacy       96%             A               7
Art                     97%             A               7

Average Year Mark:  32  with symbol  D  and code  4

Outcome: Passed

The highest mark was:  -0

The lowest mark was:  -0
*******************************************************************************

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 23.190 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: please take your time and read [ask].  Then [edit] your question to provide a [mre]

Comment: FYI, the `std::string` type should be passed by *reference* or if your function is not changing the parameter, by `const` reference.  This will avoid the compiler making a copy and passing the copy to your function.

Comment: Suggestions:  1) Use spaces not tabs.  2) Format (indent your code).

Comment: BTW, you can find the highest and lowest mark in the same pass through the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define `int low` and `int high` yet again inside your `minmax` function, if you have already defined as global variables at the beginning of the file.
Also delete them in your `main` function, as you define them there a third time. You never pass these latter as arguments to functions, so luckily they end up unused.
Here is a working version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int high, low;

void studentDetails(string Name, string Surname, string School)
{
    cout << "Please provide the following details below.";
    cout << "\nName: ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Surname: ";
    cin >> Surname;
    cout << "Name of School: ";
    cin >> School;
}
getMarks (int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){

    cout << "Please provide the mark obtained (0-100) for the following subjects.";
    cout << "\nEnglish: ";
    cin >> Eng;
    while (Eng>=0 && Eng<=100){
        cout << "Mathematics: ";
        cin >> Maths;
    while (Maths>=0 && Maths<=100){
        cout << "Life Orientation: ";
        cin >> LO;
    while (LO>=0 && LO<=100){
        cout << "History: ";
        cin >> His;
    while (His>=0 && His<=100){
        cout << "Computer Literacy: ";
        cin >> CL;
    while (CL>=0 && CL<=100){
        cout << "Art: ";
        cin >> Art;
    while (Art>=0 && Art<=100){
        cout << "All marks have been recorded";
    return 0;
}}}}}}}

void AverageYearMark(int avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    avg = (Eng + Maths + LO + His + CL + Art)/6;
    cout << "\nThe average of the above marks is: ";
    cout << avg;
}

minMax(int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    high = arr[0]; //highest mark

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        if(arr[i]>high){
            high = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Highest mark";
    cout << high;

    low = arr[0]; // lowest mark

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        if(arr[i]<low){
            low = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Lowest mark";
    cout << low;
    return 0;
}

void passorFail (string dec, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr[] = {Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    int counta = 0;
    if(Eng>= 50){
        counta++;
        for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            if(arr[i]>50){
                counta++;
            }}
        if(counta>=4){
            dec = "Pass";
        }
        else{
            dec = "Fail";
        }
            }
    else{
        dec = "Fail";
        }
    cout << dec;
}

void awardDistinction(double& avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr1[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    string arr2[6];
    string overall;
    string distinction = "distinction";
    for(int i= 0; i<6;i++){
        if(arr1[i]>=75){
            arr2[i]= distinction;
        }
        else{
            arr2[i] = " ";
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    cout << arr2[i];

    if(avg>=75){
       overall = "distinction";
    }
}

void codeSymbol(string (&symbol)[6], int (&code)[6],double& avg, int& Eng, int& Maths, int& LO, int& His, int& CL, int& Art){
    int arr1[] = {Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL, Art};
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(arr1[i]>=80 && arr1[i]<=100){
            symbol[i] = "A";
            code[i] = 7;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=70 && arr1[i]<=79){
            symbol[i] = "B";
            code[i] = 6;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=60 && arr1[i]<=69){
            symbol[i] = "C";
            code[i] = 5;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=50 && arr1[i]<=59){
            symbol[i] = "D";
            code[i] = 4;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=40 && arr1[i]<=49){
            symbol[i] = "E";
            code[i] = 3;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=30 && arr1[i]<=39){
            symbol[i] = "F";
            code[i] = 2;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>=0 && arr1[i]<=29){
            symbol[i] = "FF";
            code[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    int avcode;
    string avsym;
    if(avg<=100 && avg>=80 ){
        avcode = 7;
        avsym  = "A";
    }
    if(avg<=79 && avg>=70 ){
        avcode = 6;
        avsym  = "B";
    }
    if(avg<=69 && avg>=60 ){
        avcode = 5;
        avsym  = "C";
    }
    if(avg<=59 && avg>=50 ){
        avcode = 4;
        avsym  = "D";
    }
    if(avg<=49 && avg>=40 ){
        avcode = 3;
        avsym  = "E";
    }
    if(avg<=39 && avg>=30 ){
        avcode = 2;
        avsym  = "F";
    }
    if(avg<=29 && avg>=0 ){
        avcode = 1;
        avsym  = "FF";
    }

}

void Dispay(string& Name, string& Surname, string& School, string (&symbol)[6] , int (&mark)[6], int (&code)[6], string (subject)[6]){

cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************" << endl;
cout <<"            STUDENT ACADEMIC RECORD                            " << endl;
cout <<" This program input the learner marks of matric level subjects and prints the student final report" << endl;
cout <<"*******************************************************************************" << endl;

cout <<"Name: " + Name + " " + Surname + "  School: " + School;

cout <<"\n\nSubject \t\tMark\t\tSymbol\t\tCode" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i<6;i++){
    cout << subject[i] << "\t" << mark[i]<< "%\t\t" + symbol[i] << "\t\t" << code[i] << "\n";
}
cout << "\nAverage Year Mark: " << " 32 " << " with symbol " << " D " << " and code " << " 4 " << endl;
cout << "\nOutcome: " << "Passed" << endl;

cout << "\nThe highest mark was: " << " -" <<high<< endl;
cout << "\nThe lowest mark was: " << " -" <<low<< endl;
cout <<"*******************************************************************************" << endl;

}

int main (){
    string n; string sn; string s; string dec;
    int Eng; int Maths; int LO; int His; int CL; int Art; //int low; int high;
    double avg = 0;
    string subject[] = {"English          ","Mathematics      ","Life Orientation ","History          ","Computer Literacy","Art              "};
    string symbol[6];
    int code[6];

    studentDetails(n,sn,s);
    getMarks(Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
    int mark[] = {Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art};

    AverageYearMark(avg, Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
    minMax(Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
    passorFail(dec,Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
    awardDistinction(avg, Eng, Maths, LO, His, CL, Art);
    codeSymbol(symbol,code,avg,Eng,Maths,LO,His,CL,Art);
    Dispay(n,sn,s,symbol,mark,code,subject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is a real mess! - you have declared `int high` and `int low` in lots of different places. I did a little bit of tidying up (bit nowhere near enough). Here I basically removed all the "shadowed" instances of `int low` and `int high` to just use the global one: https://godbolt.org/z/6KWvz5

What you should do to help yourself (other then looking at your indentation and code spacing) is turn on every compiler warning you can get your hands on and make sure your code has no warnings.

Also look up "name shadowing" which is one of your issues (there are others): https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/variable-shadowing-name-hiding/

Here is the edited code again with the warning flags `-pthread -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` (and I put back in one of the shadow'd vars commented with `// THIS SHADOWS THE GLOBAL INT`: https://godbolt.org/z/9W3vY3

Please look at all the compiler warnings - treat warning like errors! - infact you can tell the compiler to do this with the flag `-Werror`.